# How can I "merge" binary data from multiple columns into a new column with categorical data?

Tags: r

My data has the following columns regarding race:

```
Black   White   Asian   Hispanic
No      Yes     No      No
Yes     No      No      No
No      No      Yes     No
No      Yes     No      Yes
...
```

I would like to combine the "White" and "Hispanic" columns into a single column where individuals are either classified as "White Non-Hispanic" or "White Hispanic". I'd also like this column to read Black and Asian, which do not need to consider Hispanic origin. I've verified that the yesses and nos are set up in a way that each row will have one of four possible outcomes: White Non-Hispanic, White Hispanic, Black, or Asian.

Ultimately I want a variable with data that looks like this (going off of the example above):

```
White Non-Hispanic
Black
Asian
White Hispanic
...
```

I have hundreds of rows of data, so I am looking for a way to automate this in R.

Comment: Does your data contain any other columns, and if so do they need to appear in the final output?

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting your expected output from the input data. How does row 1 become "White Non-Hispanic"? Where does the "Non-Hispanic" come from?

Comment: @neilfws yes, there are 40 additional columns that need to be visible.

Comment: @Maurits Evers Note how "White Non-Hispanic" corresponds to a "yes" in the "white" column and a "no" in the "Hispanic" column, while "white hispanic" corresponds to a "yes" in the "white" column and a "yes" in the "Hispanic" column.

Comment: @DanW Yes that is clear to me. Does this "rule" only apply to "white"? Can there be "black non-hispanic"?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that I'm not really clear on how you're getting your expected output from the input data (see my comment above), this might be a starting point in base R:

```r
data.frame(
    Race = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[x == "Yes"], collapse = " ")))
#            Race
#1          White
#2          Black
#3          Asian
#4 White Hispanic
```

To replace `"White"` with `"White Non-Hispanic"`, you can wrap the above inside a `transform` + `replace` call.

```r
transform(
    data.frame(
        Race = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[x == "Yes"], collapse = " "))),
    Race = replace(Race, Race == "White", "White Non-Hispanic"))
#                Race
#1 White Non-Hispanic
#2              Black
#3              Asian
#4     White Hispanic
```

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Black   White   Asian   Hispanic
No      Yes     No      No
Yes     No      No      No
No      No      Yes     No
No      Yes     No      Yes", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably not only have the different race names in one column but also have a table-like summary of how often the names have the "Yes" value. If that's correct then this should work (thanks to @Maurits for the reproducible data!):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Race") %>%
  group_by(Race) %>%
  summarise(N = sum(value == "Yes"))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Race         N
  <chr>    <int>
1 Asian        1
2 Black        1
3 Hispanic     1
4 White        2
```